# Using HttpURLConnection.getInputStream() i got huge binary file, any suggestion how write this input stream in a local file very fastely

Tags: java

we are using the below methods to save the inputstream into a file. but taking more time. Need some suggestion to optimise it. Any other method to save the input stream to line very fast.

```
InputStream stream = null;    
stream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
File imageFile = new File(directoryPath, imageFileName);
FileOutputStream imageFileStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
DigestOutputStream digestoutput = new DigestOutputStream(imageFileStream, 
md);
byte[] imagebuffer = new byte[1024 * 1024];
long size = 0;
while (true) {
if(stream != null){
int bytesRead = stream.read(imagebuffer);
if (bytesRead < 0){break;
 }
 digestoutput.write(imagebuffer, 0, bytesRead);                 
 }}
```

Comment: The speed at which you are writing the file to the disk is probably limited by the internet connection, not by the code.

Comment: You seem to have added a `DigestOuputStream` to the output pipeline ... for no reason that I can make out.  Remove it, and output will be faster.

Comment: `stream` cannot possibly be null at the point you are testing it. Don't write pointlrss code.

Comment: I would just use this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.io.InputStream-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-. No need to reivent the wheel.